# Hiragana console font for GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, fonts, console

[This guide](http://dspnet.fr.eu.org/~lonewolf/LinuxJapan/Howto_English_Japanese.html) doesn't give the information I need, saying only:

> Please be aware that japanese is not possible on purely console mode, unless you have an advanced text mode AND a special software.

Surely I don't need to create my own custom consolefont to show hiragana on the Linux console?! Or do I?

Comment: found this, though a lot is out-of-date: http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_20.html. also found the Debian kon2 package but it only works if one does not switch to a high-res console at boot. still looking...

Comment: decided to build my own using the 'nafe' package at sourceforge, which converts console font files back and forth between binary and text formats.

Comment: I suppose you speak Japanese. Also, I suppose the Japanese are proud enough to even have Kanji on their consoles (If they could fit CJK characters on NES games, which had 2KiB RAM, a console shouldn't be the hardest thing in the world). Maybe a japanese site has some info?

Comment: no, I don't speak more than a few words. Kanji would be *really* difficult with an 8-pixel-wide font; katakana easy, hiragana barely do-able. my goal with it: to make a diagnostics display of processes that resembles the Matrix "code" screens :^)

Comment: Now that I think about it, Kanji would simply not fit in 8px fonts. Did they lived all those early computer ages dealing with just hiragana, I guess? Maybe they had some way of making the fonts bigger. It makes me chuckle that they use the Yen character as a folder separator. Oh and you just got yourself +4 for the geekyness. I love the Matrix trilogy!

Comment: double-wide fonts are the way Kanji is normally done (hiragana too), but it's too much like work for me :^) thanks for the +1!

Comment: @CamiloMartin, regarding the Matrix trilogy, see http://xkcd.com/566/ bottom 4 frames! :^)

Comment: So I take it you didn't like Reloaded and Revolutions? I'd have to admit the first one was more memorable (and the one that had a lot of [similarities to Ghost in the Shell](http://youtu.be/Y3tF7TL0Qh4?t=1m26s), which is likely to have inspired it), but the second and third developed the plot, which by itself was great to see IMHO.

Comment: oh I liked them as pure entertainment, but to me they had little to do with the revolutionary message of the original. (damn, now I've gotta see Ghost in the Shell!)

Comment: Ghost in the Shell is pretty damn awesome, and though I like Japanese animation, I think it could be enjoyed by even those who aren't used to the style. Oh, and since the original was released in 1995, but remastered in 2008 as Ghost in the Shell 2.0 (not to be confused with the (also enjoyable) sequel, Ghost in the Shell 2: Innocence) to enhance the graphics and audio, you may want to look for the original if you want to feel retro (Still, they didn't mess with the movie's plot, just retouched the graphics and audio and added some CG). By the way, I have to recommend you "V for Vendetta" too.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the text consoles are not designed to show CJK characters. To display CJK characters, try `zhcon`, which is a virtual console environment that can display double-byte CJK characters.

Answer (score 1):

if any fonts are here: /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/, they need to be passed to mkinitrd to apply at boot.
do not expect good reflowing, but in general it will be spelled letter by letter and readable.